# Calculate occluded parts for planet like object

Tags: occlusion

[image]

So I have camera position (it's dynamic), planet position (also dynamic), radius and coordinates for every side (node) corners and I want to hide side that is beyond horizon (with some safety margins). I think I could easily calculate in 2D using trigonometry, but in 3D have no idea right now. I found some code online:

```
TileNode.prototype.isWithinHorizon = function () {
  var r = this.master.getRadius();
  var camToTile = this.master.getCamToTile(this);
  var camToCenter = this.master.getCamToCenter();

  var camDistToCenter = camToCenter.length();
  var dotCtCc = camToTile.dot(camToCenter.divideScalar(camDistToCenter));

  return dotCtCc - this.scale*0.5 < (camDistToCenter - r*r/camDistToCenter);
};
```

but can't make sense of it, as it is not commented. Any help appreciated!

P.S. i hope i use the term "occluded" right here

Comment: Do you store normals? If so, just check whether the camera sees the front face or not.

Comment: @tkausl no I don't store normals